# mongoDB unwind+lookup returns multiple objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

I'm trying to build a query in MongoDB in order to merge data from two collections: I have a collection of applications and a collection of features, each app contains an array of features _id and I want that each app contains an array of feature objects:

```
app{
    name,
    description,
    [requirements_id1, requirements_id2 ... ]
    } 

feature{
    name,
    description
}
```

after unwind and lookup i want to obtain something like

```
app{
    name,
    description,
    [feature1{
        name,
        description
    },      
    feature2{
        name,
        description
    }]
}
```

and i wrote this query looking at [$lookup example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in mongodb documentation

```
db.app.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$features"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "features",
            localField: "features",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "features"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "_id": '123456789' }
   }
])
```

It works but instead of a single object containing an array of features I got an array of objects containing an array which only one feature each e.g.

```
[app{
    name,
    description,
    [feature1{
        name,
        description
    }]
}

app{
    name,
    description,
    [feature2{
        name,
        description
    }]
}]
```

Of course app objects are identical except for features field. How can I get rid of that obtaining a single app containing multiple features?

Comment: Remove `$unwind` if you are on version 3.4 and above  else use `$group` on _id and `$push` the features to get the correct shape.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work simply removing $unwind from query!